# Getting comments safely into a DB with JQuery and CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, escaping

So I have a comments script I've written in Codeigniter that uses PHP and Jquery.

Basically, a user writes a comment and then hits submit. I then use AJAX to call a server side script  to check, validate and insert the comment.

At the JQuery end I am escaping using the `encodeURIComponent`

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://domain.com/ajax/post_comment',
    type : 'post',
    data : encodeURIComponent( $(this).val() ),
    success : function(data){
                //more code here
            }
});
```

At the PHP end, as I say I'm using CodeIgniter, so I am escaping the comments using the Binding provided by CodeIgniter like below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO video_comments VALUES(NULL, ?);
$this->db->query($sql,array($comment));
```

This works pretty well and can escape and insert

```
!"£$%^&*()_+=-}{~@:?></.,#;][¬`|
```

Now the problem is that, it cannot insert `'`(single quote) or `\`(backslash)? I guess because it's not escaping them properly?

One clue might be that it does allow me to insert `\'` which I guess escapes the single quote? But I would have thought CodeIgniters binding would take care of that at least?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you `var_dump($comment)` after you get the value from the AJAX post, before sending it to the DB, you will find out *where* the issue is. Have you tried inserting a string manually to make sure it's escaped? Why are you using `encodeURIComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use encodeURIComponent. That's not the intended use of it at all. 
Edit: Here's a link discussing what that call is actually for: [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Second, I don't see where you are escaping in the PHP code. CodeIgniter has built in escape functions, like escape_str:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($title)."')";
```

More info here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: Ok this works but it adds slashes, which I wanted to avoid. Can I avoid this? Or how do I output an escaped character like `\'` to look like `'`

Comment: Doesn't matter I guess I use `stripslashes` . Thanks for the answer

Comment: @EricBrandel query binding already escapes. It's written just in the page you linked, a few lines beyond the escape_str() method.

Answer (score 4):

Update: according to the discussion below query bindings makes the query safe by itself so there is no need to use escape functions separately.

IMHO, the best and secure way is to use CodeIgniter Active Record Class for your queries, if you are not too much (again too much) worried about performance. IMO, there is just slight performance improvement if you disable Active Record but there are lots of benefits if you enable and use.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: As much as this is a correct answer. Personally I feel the active records don't give you enough flexibility

Comment: I agree that Active Record is great, but how is AR "more secure" than using query bindings/placeholders?

Comment: @SeanHJenkins Where Active Record doesn't work, like sub queries, then you can use plain queries if needed, with proper sanitizing, but in the case above active record is a good way, I think.